# ubuntu 16.04 node npm issue

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I am relatively new to ubuntu and don't know why it is so hard to set up the coding environment on ubuntu.

First, I don't know what is the best way to install node,
i've used apt-get install nodejs, but I have to start with "nodejs app.js" which I really don't like to use instead of "node app.js". I've searched a several ways of installing node on ubuntu, and tried, I even forgot others ways of installing it. Now, my ubuntu can run "node" and I don't know which way I installed it.

Second, everything npm installed globally just don't work in the command line. it said :  no command "xx" found.
But I did install without errors using npm install -g xx
I just tried "npm install -g jshint"  and "npm install -g grunt-cli" and both not working in the command line.
I suspect that the package is installed but located in another directory where the command line won't get info from that directory.

I guess the question is : How to install node and npm on Ubuntu(16.04) so that I can type "node -v" to get the version, and when I install packages globally using npm, I can run it on the command line.

Comment: First question can be solved with just renaming `nodejs` to `node`. (`mv /wherever/nodejs /wherever/node`).

Comment: try to do the "whereis nodejs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most convenient way to install node.js on every OS is use `nvm`

Follow instruction in this URL:
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score -1):

by default as far as i remember, nodeJS repository in ubuntu still 0.10.x, while now already like 6.9.x

ok, lets follow this simple instruction:

first download the shell script to put the repo:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
```

then run it

```
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
```

then do apt-update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then install the nodeJS

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

optional: you might need to add these package also

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
```

by this time(October 26th, 2016) i think you should see 6.9.1 the moment you do node --version and as for npm, should be 3.10.8

Comment: btw i got this from somewhere like nodejs or digitalocean quite long time ago and i just put this script on my hard disk, and also that setup_6.x no need to be changed to setup_6.9, just leave it like that

Comment: None of your answer answers any part of the question.

Comment: what version do you get when you run nodejs --version or nodejs -v?

Comment: The question asks nothing about the Node version, just why it's installed as `nodejs` instead of `node` and why their global packages aren't working from the command line.

Comment: if you have the really old nodejs, that will probably put the alias as nodejs instead of node, i dont really remember the behavior of the old 0.10, but you can try to do "echo $PATH" and see if /usr/bin exists in your path or not, usually the installation will be there

Comment: i am answering your question "I guess the question is" and you say that this is not the answer?